# Why are two different words used for 'vision in Daniel 8:15 and 16?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, prophecy, daniel

Daniel 8 NASB

> [15]When I, Daniel, had seen the ***vision***, I sought to understand it; and behold, standing before me was one who looked like a man

וַיְהִ֗י בִּרְאֹתִ֛י אֲנִ֥י דָנִיֵּ֖אל אֶת־***הֶחָזֹ֑ון*** וָאֲבַקְשָׁ֣ה בִינָ֔ה וְהִנֵּ֛ה עֹמֵ֥ד לְנֶגְדִּ֖י כְּמַרְאֵה ־גָֽבֶר׃

.Daniel 8 NASB

> [16]And I heard the voice of a man between the banks of Ulai, and he called out and said, "Gabriel, give this man an understanding of the ***vision***."
>
> וָאֶשְׁמַ֥ע קֹול־אָדָ֖ם בֵּ֣ין אוּלָ֑י וַיִּקְרָא֙ וַיֹּאמַ֔ר גַּבְרִיאֵ֕ל הָבֵ֥ן לְהַלָּ֖ז אֶת־***הַמַּרְאֶֽה***׃

Why are two different words used for vision in the above texts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to understand the difference simply by realizing that in the *first instance* the English word for vision relates to the dream/oracle/revelation/vision Daniel was having and in the *second instance* the English word for vision refers to the vision within the vision. The distinction being between the form and the type, it took the form of a vision and he saw a type of vision.

Notice where Daniel was in the physical and where within the vision he describes himself

> “And I saw in the vision; and when I saw, I was in Susa the **citadel**, which is in the province of Elam. And I saw in the vision, and I was at the Ulai **canal**.”
>   ‭‭Daniel‬ ‭8:2‬ ‭ESV‬‬

In the physical body Daniel was at Susa citadel a province of Elam, he was inside a fortress but in the vision Daniel was at the Ulai canal by a long narrow body of water, out in the open and not within the confines of a fortress.

Notice where Daniel is described in v16 when the man begins to speak

> “And I heard a man's voice **between the banks of the Ulai**, and it called, "Gabriel, make this man understand the vision."”
>   ‭‭Daniel‬ ‭8:16‬ ‭

So the voice is speaking to him from within the vision בחזון while Daniel is having another vision המראה inside of this vision בחזון

*It may help if I inaccurately over simplify it - Daniel was dreaming and he saw a vision.* But because it wasn’t a regular dream in English (I’ll paraphrase) it’s worded as Daniel was having a vision in which he saw a separate vision.

Comment: Very instructive. Thank you. +1. May I ask, regarding your profile, which version of the Bible do you use, personally ?. (If that is not an intrusive question on my part.)

Comment: In English I don’t have a version. I’m **not** a KJVO but generally I prefer NASB for daily reading. The ESV is what I tend to use when I want to bring something out from the DSS or even the LXX. The CJB I like because of the effort that was placed into being true to the original (but it’s not always the case). I mix and match from answer to answer. There are certain times when I have to go to the NKJV but sometimes it’s only found in English in the KJV. Not to mention that knowing who the ‘you’ is important in some texts. I’m not locked in on one English version I like to parallel read texts.

Comment: Thank you. I was just interested, given the detail of your profile.

Comment: I just figured out why you asked, because I mention Bible. Hence your question of version. I only consider the original languages inspired. Translations have their place but I would never agree that the KJV is more accurate than the Hebrew or Greek. And I rely heavily on the OT. If a NT interpretation does not have any foreshadowing or backing in the OT I question the conclusions reached.

Comment: I am in agreement that it is the original Greek and Hebrew that is inspired, not the English. And I also - invariably - seek the foundation of Moses and the Prophets beneath any interpretation of the apostolic writings. I also stick, as stubbornly as I am capable of sticking - to the Textus Receptus.